# Javascript disable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dojo

I am wondering if someone can help me out with this.

I have a button defined as:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" name="myButton" value="ClickMe!!" onClick="callMe()"/>
```

I can use jQuery, standard javascript or Dojo to disable the button with onClick event:

```
$('#myButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

The problem I am facing is, even though this code disables the button, onClick event still triggers the function `callMe()` if I click on the button.

How do I make the disabled button not call the onClick function?

Comment: Check whether the button is disabled in callMe?

Comment: On a side note, you can also pass `true` like `attr('disabled', true)`, just to make it a little clearer perhaps.

Comment: @Simon, good idea but that would entail adding this check in the function even though some portions of the app doesnt need this functionality

Comment: @pimvdb, Can try your solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With jQuery you can bind a function that checks if your button is disabled:

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  if (!$(this).is(':disabled')) {
    callMe();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, use

```
$('#myButton').click(function() { callMe(); this.unbind(); });
```

instead of onClick.

Comment: Hi mblase, Actually I am using standard Javascript of this as of now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    if( !$(this).is('[disabled=disabled]') ){
       ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same code where you disable it, simply remove the onclick event handler.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, How to remove the onClick event handler?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>you should be using jQuery to attach the click handlers, not adding them inline*</sub>

Just add a check to your click function

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  var $this;
  $this = $(this);
  if ( $this.is(':disabled') ) return;
  callMe();
});
```

Alternatively,

```
$('#myButton').click(callMe);

callMe()
{
  var $this;
  $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is(':disabled')) return;
  ...the rest of your code...
}
```

Or if you insist on using it inline:

```
onclick="if ($(this).is(':disabled')) return; callMe();"
```

---

* I [regularly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382400/outsourcing-css-design-things-to-keep-in-mind-while-writing-html) [rant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937371/html-tab-interface-using-only-css) [about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255403/javascript-why-isnt-this-simple-counter-working-in-my-loop) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474427/html-minimum-attributes) [HTML, CSS & JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004789/pure-css-slider) fit the definition of MVC

Comment: Hi zzzzzBov, I dont insist on using inline. I would prefer the better solution, if you say inline isnt good, I wont use it :)

Comment: @t0mcat, I've updated my answer with links to the reasons why you should avoid inline JS.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using onclick attribute, bind to the event

```
$('#myButton').click(function(e){
    // try it without this
    if($(this).attr('disabled'))
        return false;
    callMe();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

try it without the check, not sure if its necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing.

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass("disabled")){
     //Do stuff here
  }
});
```

To disable the buttons just add the disabled class to it.

```
$('#myButton').addClass("disabled");
```

Add appropriate styles in the disabled class to make button look like disabled or you can also set the disabled property along with setting the class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ...

```
$('#myButton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

... use ...

```
$('#myButton')
   .prop('disabled', 'disabled')  // Sets 'disabled' property
   .prop('onclick', null)         // Removes 'onclick' property if found
   .off('click');                 // Removes other events if found
```